# Scikit code explanation needed

Tags: scikit-learn

Machine learning/Python Noob here. Can someone explain the below code to me? I don't understand how the below line works.

```
# This line in the code below, what does it do?
label_encoder.append(preprocessing.LabelEncoder())

label_encoder = []
X_encoded = np.empty(X.shape)
for i,item in enumerate(X[0]):
    if item.isdigit():
        X_encoded[:, i] = X[:, i]
    else:
        label_encoder.append(preprocessing.LabelEncoder())
        X_encoded[:, i] = label_encoder[-1].fit_transform(X[:, i])
```

Thanks!

Comment: It adds an instance of `LabelEncoder` to a list; that instance is fit in the subsequent line. (Voting migrate.)

Answer (score 6):

`label_encoder` is a list, which in python is an ordered collection that you can use to store any kind of object.  It is named incorrectly, it should be `label_encoders`, plurl.

We first create an empty one:

```
label_encoders = []
```

Then when we encounter the need to encode a column

```
if item.isdigit():
    # Don't need to endcode.
else:
    # Do need to encode.
```

we create a new `preprocessing.LabelEncoder()` object and save it for later use

```
label_encoders.append(preprocessing.LabelEncoder())
```

Finally, we use the most recently created `LabelEncoder` object to actually encode the column

```
X_encoded[:, i] = label_encoders[-1].fit_transform(X[:, i])
```

We *need* to store the new `LabelEncoder` objects *somewhere*, since we almost certainly will encounter a test set or new production data in the future, and will need to encode that data in the same way we encoded our training data.

I probably would have written the code like this, which is slightly clearer

```
label_encoders = []
X_encoded = np.empty(X.shape)
for i, item in enumerate(X[0]):
    if item.isdigit():
        X_encoded[:, i] = X[:, i]
    else:
        label_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
        X_encoded[:, i] = label_encoder.fit_transform(X[:, i])
        label_encoders.append(label_encoder)
```

> Thank you! I didn't realize that preprocessing.LabelEncoder() returned a list.

It doesn't!  The list comes from the line

```
label_encoders = []
```

The `preprocessing.LabelEncoder()` call returns a `LabelEncoder` type object.  This implements the [sklearn transformation interface](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/data_transforms.html), which allows you to to use the `fit_transform` and `transform` methods to encode your features.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that preprocessing.LabelEncoder() returned a list. The final append makes more sense now.

Comment: @adamcamroon I think you still have a misunderstanding.  I edited a bit more explanation into my answer.